# Are all routes accessible and their component data from Angular 2 Bundle?

Tags: angular2-routing

I feel like I am misunderstanding a crucial element in Angular 2 development. From what I understand, the client downloads a Bundle.js, containing all of the components and routes for the application. However, if some of those routes are meant to be protected with user authentication, wouldn't that make Angular 2 Bundles extremely insecure? Could't the client just look into the Bundle.js file to find out all of the information about any route he desired since it is all at his fingertips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more experience in Angular, I now feel like this is a dumb question, but will answer it anyway for other people new to front end development. Yes, any client can look into the code given to them, manipulate it, and do whatever they want.

The whole point of an API is to secure data and ensure it is distributed properly, so that no matter who tampers with a front end bundle, they can only receive certain data if they have the proper credentials, which they cannot manipulate or fake (I use JWT)